# Fibonacci mod number c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci, modulo

I have the following problem:
I should compute a fibonacci number mod another given number. I know about the Pisano period and i am trying to implement it here. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
long long get_fibonaccihuge(long long n, long long m) {
    long long period = 0;
    if (m % 2 == 0) {
        if(m / 2 > 1)
        period = 8 * (m / 2) + 4;
        else
        period = 3; 
    }
    else{
        if(((m + 1) / 2) > 1)
        period = 4 * ((m + 1) / 2);
        else
        period = 1;
    }

    long long final_period = n % period;



    long long array_fib[final_period];
    array_fib[0] = 1;
    array_fib[1] = 1;
    for (long long i = 2; i < final_period; ++i) {
        array_fib[i] = (array_fib[i-1] + array_fib[i-2]) % m;
    }

    return array_fib[final_period - 1];
}

int main() {
    long long n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::cout << get_fibonaccihuge(n, m) << '\n';
}
```

It works well for small tests but the problem is that it fails the following test:

281621358815590 30524

I do not know why. Any suggestions about the algorithm, I referred to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) page. When I was constructing it.

The error which I receive is: wrong result.

Expected: 11963 My result: 28651

Comment: `long long array_fib[final_period]` uses a g++ language extension (namely C99 variadiac arrays). In standard C++ use `std::vector<long long> array_fib(final_period)`. This is not your logic problem but I thought I should mention it: better post standard code that everyone can try.

Comment: I know that the mistake should be at the moment when I obtain the number mod period,

Comment: What fails? Run time error? Wrong result? What is your output?

Comment: What is your result? What is the expected result?

Comment: Add that to your question, I'd suggest.

Comment: You confirm that `m` is the Fibonacci index and `n` is the Fibonacci number? If so, then that's wrong I think.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/puremathematics/comments/yc6hv/i_have_solved_the_pisano_periods_a_250_year_old/

Answer (score 2):

Unless your task is to use Pisano periods, I would suggest you to use a more common known way to calculate n-th Fibonacci number in log2(n) steps (by computing powers of 2*2 matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form).

There are two reasons:

1. It's a simpler algorithm and that means that it will be easier to debug the program
2. For the numbers you mentioned as an example it should be faster (log2(n) is somewhere about 50 and m/2 is significantly more).

Comment: Does this approach keep the numbers within 64 bits integer size?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: All intermediate numbers will be less that m*m, so 64-bit numbers will be enough. The biggest number will be the n itself but it's within 64-bit range too.